# react button change colors in few different components

Tags: reactjs

lets say we have a website, which inside are 3 group,
each group have 3 different colored buttons, and a title that change colors depends on the buttons you clicked.

i wanna do this using ONE buttons component,
the real question is, how do i let my 3 Buttons component know, which title's group it needs to change???

i guessed using props? but still not sure at all, i will love to hear your ideas cause im sure they will be better than mine!

thanks guys!!

here a image of what im trying to do[image: how it looks]

homepage component:

```
class Homepage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.changeGroup = this.changeGroup.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        changeColor: null
    }
}

changeGroupColor= (event) => {
    var color = event.target.id;
    this.setState({
        changeColor: color
    })
    } 

   <div className="group1">
      <h1>im title of group1</h1>
      <Buttons /> // i will change the h1 of group 1
   </div>
   <div className="group2">
      <h1>im title of group2</h1>
      <Buttons /> // i will change the h1 of group 2
   </div>
   <div className="group3">
      <h1>im title of group3</h1>
      <Buttons /> // i will change the h1 of group 3
   </div>
```

Buttons component: the ID on each color is a hex color code

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        colors: DATA
    }
}
render(){
return(
<div className="container">
    {
        this.state.colors.map(({ key, id }) => (
            <p className="buttons"
                id={id}
                key={key}
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: id 
                }}
                onClick={(event) =>this.props.changeGroupColor(event)}
                >button
                </p>
        ))
    }
    </div>
```

const DATA

```
const DATA = [
{
    key: 1,
    id: "#ff9966"
},
{
    key: 2,
    id: "#66d9ff"
},
{
    key: 3,
    id: "#ff66b3"
}
]
 export default DATA;
```

Comment: Use an object for the titles that each have a unique key so that when the button is clicked to change, the changes will be mapped appropriately to the corresponding title based on the key.